# Importing Joomla! database into Prestashop, but the salting of passwords is different

Tags: php, joomla, passwords, salt, prestashop

My boss asked me to import a Joomla! database of about 250 users into a Prestashop database (of users).

After some analysis, I've found out that Prestashop and Joomla! use different password salting techniques.

So my question is: "Are we doomed yet?"

And how can I overcome the import when the password salt of the source won't be compatible to the destination?

Comment: Anything is possible with enough coffee and relaxed workplace restrictions on cursing.

Comment: Your headache is going to be minimised by resetting all passwords, notifying all users that their passwords are reset, and when they log in again, must change them. Good luck.

Comment: You can always make two logins. First, check if the user/password exist in the Prestashop database. If not, look in the Joomla database. Optionally import the Joomla login to Prestashop.

Comment: You may want a relevant title so that someone who has the right knowledge is more likely to look at this rather than people who are looking to moderate or get a chuckle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are for a direct import.  Joomla's salting mechanism is pretty decent, so don't bother try breaking it (you can, but it'll take a while to do it for all 250 users).

Instead, what you could do is import all the records into the other database with the exception of the password column (Leave it blank).

Then, write a plugin that on a successful login into Joomla will check the other DB and update the password there...

I'm not familiar with Prestashop, but you should be able to write some code that would check for a blank password when they login, and present a message to login to Joomla first.

Either that, or write a single-sign-on system so that all authentication goes through Joomla (which is what I would do, since then you only have 1 place to manage users, instead of two)...